# Trouble doing a simple Box Plot

Tags: r, visualization

This is a problem that I keep having when trying to do a `boxplot` in `R`. From what I can see the code I am using should work, not only that but when compared to my notes and other classmates it appears to be the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
result <- read.csv("keough.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", dec= ",")
head(result)

 BIOFILM.SERP    
1        SL,61
2       SL,113
3       SL,123
4        SL,75
5        SL,75
6        SL,83

attach(result)
boxplot(BIOFILM~SERP, dat=result)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'BIOFILM' not found

Comment: Looks like an import error.

Comment: your import is wrong, try with sep=“, “ inside read.csv

Comment: On a side note: using `attach`/`detach` is not good practice, especially when working with multiple datasets.

Answer (score 0):

```
result <- read.csv(“Keough.csv”, header=TRUE, sep=“,”, dec=“,”)
```